# semaphore synchronization going wrong, in producer consumer example

Tags: c, synchronization, semaphore, producer-consumer

I am trying to code a single producer-consumer problem, as shown below. I will pass the incremented value of i through the shared memory. However, i find that the initial value sent by the producer is missing, producer sends 0, but consumer fails to capture 0, and instead captures from 1. I dont understand why this is happening. The server writes 0 into the shared memory, and waits on empty, and as soon as the client program starts running, even before the initial value is read, empty is released in the producer some how, and it writes 1. 0 goes missing here. I am specifying the code of both the processes here.

Semaphore_Server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

struct a
{
    int a;
    int b;
} a_s;

void wait(int semid)
{
    int err,nsops=1;
    struct sembuf *sopwait = (struct sembuf *) malloc(sizeof(struct sembuf));
    sopwait[0].sem_num = 0;
    sopwait[0].sem_op = -1;
    sopwait[0].sem_flg = 0;
    err = semop(semid, sopwait, nsops);
    if(err < 0)
        printf(" unable to do the sop \n");
}

void signal(int semid)
{
    int err,nsops=1;
    struct sembuf *sops = (struct sembuf *) malloc(sizeof(struct sembuf));      
    sops[0].sem_num = 0;
    sops[0].sem_op = 1;
    sops[0].sem_flg = 0;
    err = semop(semid, sops, nsops);
    if(err < 0)
        printf(" unable to do the sop \n");
}

int main()
{
    int i, err;
    int full,empty;
    key_t full_key = 1234, empty_key = 5678;
    int sem_flg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;
    int nsems = 1;
    int nsops = 2;
    int shmid;
    void *string;
    void *s;
    int shm_key = 9999;

    struct a *a_str = (struct a*)malloc(sizeof(struct a));
    /*****************************************/

    empty = semget(empty_key, nsems, sem_flg);
    if(empty < 0)
        printf(" failed to initialize the semaphore \n");

    semctl(empty, 0, SETVAL, 1) ;
    /****************************************/
    full = semget(full_key, nsems, sem_flg);
    if(full < 0)
        printf(" failed to initialize the semaphore \n");

    semctl(full, 0, SETVAL, 0) ;    

    /*****************************************/
    shmid = shmget(shm_key, 30, IPC_CREAT|0666); 
    if(shmid < 0) 
        printf(" unable to create shmem \n");
    else
        printf(" created shm \n");

    string = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0); 
    if(string == (void * ) (-1))
        printf(" unable to attach the string \n");
    else
        printf(" success with shmat \n");
    s = string;
    /******************************************/
    i = 0;
    while(i < 20)
    {
        wait(empty);
        a_str->a = i;
        memcpy( string, (void *) a_str, sizeof(struct a));
        printf(" wrote the string %d \n", i);
        i++;
        signal(full);
    }
}
```

Semaphore _client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

struct a
{
    int a;
    int b;
} a_s;

void wait(int semid)
{
    int err,nsops=1;
    struct sembuf *sopwait = (struct sembuf *) malloc(sizeof(struct sembuf));
    sopwait[0].sem_num = 0;
    sopwait[0].sem_op = -1;
    sopwait[0].sem_flg = 0;
    err = semop(semid, sopwait, nsops);
    if(err < 0)
        printf(" unable to do the sop \n");
}

void signal(int semid)
{
    int err,nsops=1;
    struct sembuf *sops = (struct sembuf *) malloc(sizeof(struct sembuf));      
    sops[0].sem_num = 0;
    sops[0].sem_op = 1;
    sops[0].sem_flg = 0;
    err = semop(semid, sops, nsops);
    if(err < 0)
        printf(" unable to do the sop \n");
}

int main()
{
    int i, err;
    int full,empty;
    key_t full_key = 1234, empty_key = 5678;
    int sem_flg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;
    int nsems = 1;
    int nsops = 2;
    int shmid;
    void *string;
    void *s;
    int shm_key = 9999;

    struct a *a_str = (struct a*)malloc(sizeof(struct a));
    /*****************************************/

    empty = semget(empty_key, nsems, sem_flg);
    if(empty < 0)
        printf(" failed to initialize the semaphore \n");

    semctl(empty, 0, SETVAL, 1) ;
    /****************************************/
    full = semget(full_key, nsems, sem_flg);
    if(full < 0)
        printf(" failed to initialize the semaphore \n");

    semctl(full, 0, SETVAL, 0) ;    

    /*****************************************/
    shmid = shmget(shm_key, 30, IPC_CREAT|0666); 
    if(shmid < 0) 
        printf(" unable to create shmem \n");
    else
        printf(" created shm \n");

    string = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0); 
    if(string == (void * ) (-1))
        printf(" unable to attach the string \n");
    else
        printf(" success with shmat \n");
    s = string;
    /******************************************/
    i = 0;
    while(i < 20)
    {
        wait(full);
        memcpy((void *)a_str, (void *)s, sizeof(struct a));
        printf(" a %d \n",((struct a *)a_str)->a);
        i++;
        signal(empty);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

could anybody tell me why server writes twice, before the client reads once? 
here is the output from the server. 
    wrote the string 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

client output : 
    a 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

Comment: Why do you not use the better POSIX IPC API?

Comment: because that requires linking with -lpthreads which i prefer to avoid.. this method is used somewhere else in our project.. and its working fine with them. i dont know whats going wrong here.

Comment: inwhich ways posix API is better?

Comment: Well, it is simpler, and easier to use.

Comment: @leelduhem, Thanks, I am trying with lpthreads, but i would still like to know what could go wrong with this one. I couldnt pick whats going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> could anybody tell me why server writes twice, before the client reads once?

This is easy to fix, remove those two calls to `semctl()` in your `Semaphore _client.c`.

Explanation:

1. if server run first, it will write 0 to shared memory, and wait at `wait(empty);`; but once you call `semctl(empty, 0, SETVAL, 1);` in client, that wait in server will return and server may begin to write 1, in this case, the 0 will be lost.
2. if client run first, your code will work properly.